# Perl - separate variable name from types

Tags: regex, perl

I have these strings:

```
int name
const int level
const char          *  const                    format
(float) int promenna
(char *) int jina
```

How can I separete in perl that name of variables (name, level, format, ...) from rest? I tried some regular expresion as `/((\.*\s*\w+)+)(\s+)(\w+)$/` but I am not very good at that and I have problem with my. So do anyone has easy solution? And in third example there are many spaces and you must count with that, there could be \s*. Thank you

Edit: I bad explain what I want. I said I want separate name and I mean I need remove last word (variable name) from string. I am sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: In order to do this, you need to have a list of key words and basically treat everything else as a variable name. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, I can´t have list of key words because It must be working with users structures and types. Elementary I just need remove last word from string but I need to keep number of space characters between other words.

Comment: That clarifies the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the split function on each line and take the last element of the result array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just substitute the last 'word' for nothing, using

```
s/\w+$//
```

eg:

```
#!perl

my @strings = (
    'int name',
    'const int level',
    'const char          *  const                    format',
    '(float) int promenna',
    '(char *) int jina',
    'char *a'
);

for my $string (@strings) {
    $string =~ s/\w+$//;
    $string =~ s/\s*$//;
    $string =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    print "$string\n";
}
```

results in

```
int
const int
const char * const
(float) int
(char *) int
char *
```

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for but I more thing. What about if I had char *a and I need char *? Now I get char *a. Thank you

Comment: Updated to handle that case. It now leaves trailing spaces on the line, but that can be handled by chomp or another regex if needed.

Comment: It´s exactly what I need (just add one more regex for removing trailing spaces). Thank you